# Ansible playbook execution using Jenkins on remote node throwing file or directory not found error

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I have been trying to run Ansible `playbook.yml` file from Jenkins using Jenkins's Ansible plugin, but it is throwing file or directory is not found error. However, I  crossed checked paths more than one time and they are correct. The `playbook.yml` also exists on the appropriate path. I also verified sshpass. Its latest version is installed on the linux master node.

Please note that. I have properly created the passwordless ssh connection between two Linux VMs machines. I am installing packages from Master Linux node to the slave Linux node using the `playbook.yml` file. My Jenkins is installed on window machine and I am using ansible plugin from there. I also added both Linux machines on Jekins node managements.

This is the error:

```
Started by user Admin
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on Linux_Master_Nodes (Linux_Master_Node) in workspace /data/jenkins/workspace/Invoke_Ansible_Playbook
[Invoke_Ansible_Playbook] $ sshpass ******** /data/ansible/ansible-playbook /data/ansible/playbooks/playbook.yml -f 5 -u root -k
sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory
FATAL: command execution failed
hudson.AbortException: Ansible playbook execution failed
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:262)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:232)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:79)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1816)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
ERROR: Ansible playbook execution failed
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

> sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory

sshpass cannot run the command passed as argument.

Did you check that ansible is correctly installed on the jenkins slave in the path given on the command line ?

Comment: I installed it. I also cross checked it. It is there in the Linux_master_Nodes. I also created ssh passwordless connection between nodes..

Comment: Did you check your `PATH` variable for jenkins user on the slave to make sure sshpass is in there ?

Comment: OK. I just got all this wrong. The message means that `sshpass` itself could not excute the command given as argument.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect our conversation.

Comment: yes you are right. is it not ssh key sharing enough for the connection?

Comment: It is the command that is not recognized at all e.g. `sshpass -psecret echo toto => toto` vs `sshpass -psecret unexistant_command => sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory`. My guess is that `/data/ansible/ansible-playbook` does not exists on your remote node.

Comment: Other possibility is that your jenkins credential is not prepended with a `-p` option (and sshpass would think the password is the command) but I doubt the ansible jenkins plugin has such a bug (or I would already have tons of tickets from users :))

Comment: Yes, I saw those bugs and tried enough to resolve the issue but I thought that it could have been resolved by someone. BTW I changed the directory settings of Ansible directory. It is working fine without Jenkins...